# Can I resist Magic at full strength with the Become Ethereal Shout?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to know if I can resist Magic with the Become Ethereal Shout, before I set out to find the other parts to it.

I have tried to use it at the beginning one but I die anyway.

Comment: and how do i gain reputation

Comment: Reputation is gained mostly through upvotes on your questions and answers. I suggest you take the [tour] of the site, it explains it quite well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all damage will be ignored while using the shout. For this shout, every added word only increases duration and cooldown, and has no effect on it beyond.

Source: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Become_Ethereal

> *Shouting additional words increases the duration and cooldown of the
>   effect. *

And

> *Can be used to quickly negate massive amounts of damage from dragon
>   breath attacks.*

But, if you attack while in the form, you will immediately break it.

> *However, any damaging attacks performed while the shout is active will
>   immediately end the effect.*